# Can no longer install anything or upgrade on lubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, lubuntu

The lubuntu version I have is:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:        19.10
Codename:       eoan
```

When I try to install anything, I get these errors about sources:

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answers about this in other threads say to go into Software Sources and uncheck basically everything, and then only enable main. However, when I enable just main and close, it says:

> Your local copy of the software catalog is out of date. A new copy will be downloaded.

So I hit `Reload` and it says

```
pk-client-error-quark: E: The repository 'http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
 (319)
```

So now I am stuck. How can I install anything now?

---

I understand that 19.10 is no longer supported. I would be happy to upgrade. However, I cannot seem to upgrade either. When I follow [this guide](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/D/upgrading.html) on upgrading, it says to run

`sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`

However, this encounters the same error about sources as above!

How can I make any progress here?

---

**Edit**: I have tried the solution in [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release). This allows me to fetch a release file. However, I still remain fundamentally impeded. When I follow the instructions in that post to upgrade my distribution, I receive the following error:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

When I look at `main.log` I see:

```
2021-01-21 13:30:18,069 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg']'
2021-01-21 13:30:18,069 INFO uname information: 'Linux andromeda 5.3.0-64-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 19:33:51 UTC 2020 x86_64'
2021-01-21 13:30:18,296 INFO apt version: '1.9.4ubuntu0.1'
2021-01-21 13:30:18,296 INFO python version: '3.7.5 (default, Apr 19 2020, 20:18:17) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008]'
2021-01-21 13:30:18,298 INFO release-upgrader version '20.04.29' started
2021-01-21 13:30:18,307 INFO locale: 'en_DK' 'UTF-8'
2021-01-21 13:30:18,354 DEBUG screen returned: 'There is a screen on:
        21705.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window      (2021-01-21 13:27:45)   (Attached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.
'
2021-01-21 13:30:18,354 INFO found active screen session, re-attaching
```

which appears unhelpful. There is no file `apt.log`.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for the link. However, it did not really work fully. I have edited the post with new details.

Comment: @mook765 Actually, it has worked now. I was running it within a screen session and this apparently caused problems.